# How to pass only some properties of an object in method parameters to Fody/MethodTimer Interceptor

Tags: c#, fody

I want to log the execution time for my methods by **Fody/MethodTimer**.

**I Cannot pass only some properties of my methods' parameters (which are a class type).**

My Method :

```
[Time("'{obj.EventId}'")]
private static void testFody(TestClass obj)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     {
          Console.WriteLine($"This is : {i }");
     }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }

    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    public int prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error :

> Could not process 'System.Void
>   TestCurrentEPCIS.Program::testFody(TestCurrentEPCIS.TestClass)'
>   because the format uses 'obj.EventId' which is not available as method
>   parameter.

And when I pass the object itself as following, it passes obj.ToString() to Interceptor class:

```
[Time("'{obj}'")]
private static void testFody(TestClass obj)
```

***How can I pass some properties of my obj parameters to Interceptor??***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer/blob/master/readme.md#using-parameters-inside-the-logging), this is currently something that is not supported:

> Note 1: sub-properties are not (yet?) supported.

The weaver only supports two types of arguments via the attribute:

> The following values are allowed:
>
> - Any parameter name (e.g. {fileName})
> - {this} (**calls ToString() on the instance itself**) Note that this is not available on static methods, the weaver will throw an error if
>     being used in a static method

(emphasis mine)

It seems that the only thing that you *could* do is include the properties in an overridden `ToString` method.

The weaver is open-source. If you have time that you can dedicate to this, you may consider forking the project and making the necessary updates. A good place to start seems to be the [ParameterFormattingProcessor](https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer/blob/master/MethodTimer.Fody/ParameterFormattingProcessor.cs) class which is using a basic Regex to identify the parameter name.

Answer (score -1):

Eventid is Guid typed property, and needs to initialize it, so please try below code:

```
 public class TestClass
    {
   private Guid _EventId;
   public Guid EventId { 
      get=> (_Eventid = 
          _Eventid==null ?  Guid.NewGuid() :
           _Eventid);

      set=>_EventId=value; 
         }

        public string prop1 { get; set; }

        public int prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer but it's not the problem. The problem is that Fody maps exact "obj.EventId" with the method's parameters and says that I cannot find such a parameter.